# WSO2 api manager gateway cluster configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

While attempting to create a cluster for my API Manager I'm confused on some of the documentation.
Here is the architecture:
MS SQL Server as the database.
Single node VM that runs both the Publisher and the Store.
2 additional nodes that run the gateway and key manager.

The documentation says to install the different components by copying the same install over and over...but that doesn't make sense to me.  I want the publisher and store to run together (just like a stand alone), and I want the gateway and key manager to run together (again, like a stand alone), but be clustered for throughput.

When I use this guide:
http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager

It indicates in step 10a-b that we should update:  to point to WSO2REG_DB.  However, this configuration item doesn't even exist.  It also has additional configuration that does exist...

```
<remoteInstance url="https://publisher.apim-wso2.com">    
<id>gov</id>   <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>   <readOnly>false</readOnly>           
<enableCache>true</enableCache>   <registryRoot>/</registryRoot></remoteInstance>
<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
<targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath></mount>
```

and again for the store (except the remoteInstance url is slightly different).
Can I simply point the default config for the file registry.xml to point to WSO2REG_DB and leave the remote instance configuration the default stand alone for my publisher/store node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Since you have asked multiple questions in your query ill break it down and answer

1.Node clustering- If you are using API Manager 1.5 or below you can use the same instance and run them as Store/Pub and Gateway/KM node. For the Gateway/KM node you can remove the jaggery files that will remove the UI from the API Manager instance. If you are using API Manager 1.6 then you can start each instance in different profiles. Please refer to the link below 
http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Running+the+Product+on+a+Preferred+Profile

2 WSO2REG_DB config- please add this config to the registry.xml.  Please change the govregistry configuration as mentioned in the document. Have only 1 remote Instance configuration for both publisher and store since they are both in a single instance

Comment: Thank you for the response...I am using API Manager 1.5, I've removed the jaggery files previously on the gateway/key manager nodes.  I'll try the suggest configuration and reply back.

Comment: I implemented as described: <dbConfig name="govregistry"> <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource> </dbConfig> <remoteInstance url="redacted.url.com"> <id>gov</id> <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig> <readOnly>false</readOnly> <enableCache>true</enableCache> <registryRoot>/</registryRoot> </remoteInstance> <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true"> <instanceId>gov</instanceId> <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath> </mount>

Comment: When starting the publisher/store now I get: ERROR RegistryCoreServiceComponent Unable to create fixed remote mounts.  org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null.  Later in the log there is a java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of committed connections.  I have set 100 as my maxactive config setting.  The change for the registry.xml file and increasing my maxactive are the only config changes between a working instance of the store and this one that fails.

Comment: -DBcfg:<datasource><name>WSO2REG_DB</name><description>desc</description><jndiConfig><name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name></jndiConfig><definitiontype="RDBMS"><configuration><defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit><url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:port/regdb</url><username>user</username><password>pwd</password><driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName><maxActive>100</maxActive><maxWait>60000</maxWait><testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow><validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery><validationInterval>30000</validationInterval></configuration></definition></datasource>

Comment: Thanks for the help...even though the registry doesn't yet work, the principle seems like it should.  I'll do more research and post a more targeted question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying distributed deployment of WSO2 Api Manager.

In the guide you mentioned its using same product binary for all four distributed components, but configuring them to use only required components accessed in each node.

And according to your question you need publisher and store run on one node together, and gateway and key manager to run on another node together. So what you have to do is following the documentation you mentioned carefully by doing both publisher/store changes in one node and both gateway/keymanager changes in other node.

Step 10 a-b points to WSO2REG_DB, which is created in Step 7 d. Before change the deployment, i would suggest to follow the document as it is, because it would help you to understand about the deployment.

You would need to have full configuration in 10 a & b, but since you have only one node, you have to have only one registry.xml with a sample configuration as follows,

```
<dbConfig name="govregistry">
  <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
<remoteInstance url="https://store_publisher.apim-wso2.com"> 
   <id>gov</id>
   <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
   <readOnly>false</readOnly>
   <enableCache>true</enableCache>
   <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>
<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Keep in mind to add the mapping to custom host name 'store_publisher.apim-wso2.com' used above to /etc/hosts file as follows,

```
xx.xxx.x.206 store_publisher.apim-wso2.com
```

which also explained in file as explained in 10-c.

Regards,
DarRay

Comment: I'm assuming that it is permissible to use dns entries rather than the hosts file in all cases?

Comment: Should the remoteInstance point to the server the store/publisher is on?  i.e.  https://localhost

Comment: I implemented as described: <dbConfig name="govregistry"> <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource> </dbConfig> <remoteInstance url="redacted.url.com"> <id>gov</id> <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig> <readOnly>false</readOnly> <enableCache>true</enableCache> <registryRoot>/</registryRoot> </remoteInstance> <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true"> <instanceId>gov</instanceId> <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath> </mount>

Comment: When starting the publisher/store now I get: ERROR RegistryCoreServiceComponent Unable to create fixed remote mounts. org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null. Later in the log there is a java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of committed connections. I have set 100 as my maxactive config setting. The change for the registry.xml file and increasing my maxactive are the only config changes between a working instance of the store and this one that fails

Comment: DB:<datasource><name>WSO2REG_DB</name><description>desc</description><jndiCo‌nfig><name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name></jndiConfig><definitiontype="RDBMS"><configurat‌ion><defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit><url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server‌:port/regdb</url><username>user</username><password>pwd</password><driverClassNam‌e>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName><maxActive>100</maxActive><ma‌xWait>60000</maxWait><testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow><validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery><validationInterval>30000</validationInterval></configuration‌></definition></datasource>

Comment: I didn't got your second comment. Can you please clarify it.

Comment: For the next two comments its seems like configurations are correct. To isolate the issue, I would suggest to try out, commenting out the parts added in 10-a\b and try to start the server.

Comment: <remoteInstance url="https://cerntestapistore.cernerasp.com"> <id>gov</id> <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig> <readOnly>false</readOnly> <enableCache>true</enableCache> <registryRoot>/</registryRoot> </remoteInstance> <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true"> <instanceId>gov</instanceId> <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath> </mount>

Comment: Which then error with: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} - Unable to create fixed remote mounts. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} -  Failed to commit transaction. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager}
java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of committed connections

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager} -  Failed to close transaction. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.dataaccess.TransactionManager}
java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of closed connections

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.internal.UserMgtInitializer} - While adding management permission :: Failed to close transaction. {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.internal.UserMgtInitializer} org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to close transaction.  ...and repeats the commit/close errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help...even though the registry doesn't yet work, the principle seems like it should.  I'll do more research and post a more targeted question.