# How to publish APIs in wso2 API manager on gateway running on different servers.?

Tags: wso2

Suppose i have a scenario where multiple servers are acting as gateway.Now I publish an API on my publisher application which is running on another server.I want to know the process that how my application will get publish at each gateway..?

Comment: Have you used master-worker pattern to configure multiple gateway nodes? Generally the api being published will be updated on gateway nodes through webservice call.

Comment: i want to know the process of how it happens.Does there is some files written somewhere that needs to be sync .Reason being i am relying on DB for syncing the information b/w different servers

Answer (score 0):

This is done via clustering where whenever an API is published from the API Manager the API Gateway nodes are notified of this. Please refer to the clustering guide below
http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Clustering+API+Manager

Comment: I am doing this by writing a script which copies repository/deployment/server in each of the instances of wso2.Things seems to work pretty much is there a problem with this approach.

Comment: This will only sync API artifacts between instances in the deployment,  you need to mount the API Manager's config and gov space to a common repository. Please refer to the clustering guide and follow the instructions. you can skip the deployment sync part as your doing it through a script

Comment: while mounting i am facing the same issue as mentioned here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173955/wso2-api-manager-gateway-cluster-configuration

Comment: In addition to above since i am using same instance for publisher and store so i suppose i already have gov space to common repository

Comment: config and gov space should be common to all API Manager components in your deployment.